# Handle Enter key for many edit texts

Tags: android

I have a form having some 20 edit text controls. What changes should I make so that, on press of "Enter", the control should go to the next edit text.

Solution:

```
EditText edit=new EditText(this); 
edit.setSingleLine();
```

This works for me.

My issue is solved Thanks to the Chat room.

Comment: Why would you want the user to press enter every other time and then switch to the next `EditText`? Instead he/she can do that directly. Don't you think so?

Comment: use this attributes in your edit text "android:nextFocusDown"

Comment: what do you mean by "press of enter"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText edit=new EditText(this); 
edit.setSingleLine();
```

This worked for me. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use imeOptions in your EditText's xml to define the required action:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Answer (score 0):

override this method in your activity and reply if it goes good

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
{  if (event == null || event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) 
{  //do my calcs
  return(true);//reset key event for next press
 }  
 }
```